# What is difference in using gerund and infinitive?

Tags: infinitives, gerunds

What is the difference between sentences below?

> The government ceased providing free health care.

and

> The government ceased to provide free health care.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. 1 is correct.

No. 2 is correct, but sounds awkward compared to #1. In this case, the infinitive following the verb "ceased" is acting as its direct object. But as you have pointed out, using a gerund would be a simpler construction. I suspect some people favor this construction because it sounds more "official" or like legal writing.

A better use of an infinitive following a verb should describe the purpose or intent of that action:  **The government has ceased the health care program *to save money*.**  (The infinitive "to save" describes the intent of "ceased."

Other uses of the infinitive:

**After an adjective, to specify what the adjective describes**: *It is costly to provide free health care.*

**After a noun, to indicate purpose**: *The government passed a law to provide free healthcare.*

**As a subject**: *To provide free health care is the purpose of the law.*